# Scratched at and stabbed at

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What's the difference between "scratched/stabbed" and "scratched at/stabbed at"?

Example sentences:

> He scratched (at) his ear.
>
> It stabbed (at) her heart.

Comment: The at merely creates the image of an implement as image used to carry out the action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you stab someone, you will injure him; the blade will cut his flesh.

If you stab *at* someone, you are trying to injure him, but you miss.  (Indeed, *stab* as noun is sometimes used to mean *attempt*, as in “Let’s take a stab at cleaning that stain.”)

“Scratch at” is different.

I have never heard anyone say “scratch at” to mean “attempt to scratch”.  You might “swipe at” someone, with your hand (or paw) in such a position that if you do manage to connect, you could do some damage.

Instead, “at” suggests that the scratch is done not to injure or damage the target, but for some other purpose.

If a dog scratches at the door, he wants you to open it.  If a student scratches at his ear, the ear doesn’t itch; he is just doing it as an idle gesture.

(By this logic, when you are thinking, you should “scratch at your head”, but nobody says that.  The phrase is “scratch your head”, even though you are not trying to draw blood.  English is funny.)

Comment: Yes, like in some prose giving account on someone's behavior: " ... scratched at his ear absentmindedly". Or, "... furrowing his brows, he pondered the alternatives; his hand found his earlobe, scratching at it. Abruptly he slammed his boots on the wooden floor, leaned forward in his chair and looked the visitors in the eye: 'I think I know what we're 'bout to do' he said."

Comment: Like most people, I'd normally include the preposition ***at*** in the context of talking about someone [*stabbing **at** me with his finger*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22stabbing+at+me+with+his+finger%22) But certainly in ***that*** context, I'd be less likely to be "injured" than if someone was actually ***scratching*** me (and very probably, ***drawing blood***).

Comment: (If the dog scratches ***at*** the door, you'll probably *hear* it if you're around, but it won't necessarily leave any permanent marks on the door. On the other hand, I'd say that *by definition*, if the dog ***scratches*** the door, this will leave permanent scratch marks.)